# Parsing a multi line flat file in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How do i parse a multi line file using UTL_FILE? In the below example snippet -
The line starting with '1' is the File header - one per file.
The line starting with '5' is the transaction header - one per transaction
The line starting with '8' is the transaction trailer - one per transaction
The line starting with '9' is the file footer - one per file.

I need logic to 1) read the file lines and 2) to be able to distinguish where a transaction starts and ends. Per line, I know Oracle has the instr and substr to distinguish different values in it.

Any suggestions would be welcome! Thanks for your time.

```
1TreasuryPart    201610031830MEMO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
53336      Bank1Base0000001                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
650   3100000126         1-30-00010-00     000002126100000000000000021261USD20161003RAYMOND SOLIS         jane.doe@gmail.com                  205-888-9900                            20161003020030000001                    WEBENRAPC34560000000000                  WEB                    
800000000010000000212610000000000000000001                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
53336      Bank1Base0000002                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
800000000000000000000000000000000000000002                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
53343      ToddMUD     0000001                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
800000000000000000000000000000000000000001                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
53343      ToddMUD     0000002                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
800000000000000000000000000000000000000002                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
53351      DenisTM     0000001                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
650   3100000128         7779026           000004000000000000000000080000USD20161003Denis Pellerin        jack.doe@gmail.com                                              405-922-2116        20161003100421000001                    WEBUNEAPC34560000000000                  WEB                    
650   3100000128         7779026           000004000000000000000000080000USD20161003Denis Pellerin        jack.doe@gmail.com                                              405-922-2116        20161003100421000002                    WEBUNEAPC34560000000000                  WEB                    
800000000020000000800000000000000000000001                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
53351      DenisTM     0000002                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
800000000000000000000000000000000000000002                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
9000006000000000003000000101261000000000000
```

Comment: What have you tried and what problem(s) are you having?  You say that you want to use `utl_file` rather than, say, `SQL*Loader` so I assume you know how to call `get_line` to read a line from the file.  You know that you can use `substr` and `instr` to get the first character of that line.  You'd need some sort of local state variable to tell you whether you've already read, say, a 1 and a 5 and are therefore reading transaction rows (and to know how to parse those rows).

Comment: I have defined 1 record for a 1, 1 record for any number of 5's, 1 record for any number of 6's, 1 record for any number of 8's, and 1 record for a 9. I have also done a utl_file.fgetattr to check for file existence. I also have the parsing into the record variables per record.As i mentioned, i am stuck on how to read from the first line to the next, and when to figure out where transaction A ends and transaction B starts. In the example above, it is a valid case to have two consecutive 6's too between the 5 and the 8.

Comment: I don't know what "read from the first line to the next" means.  I would interpret that as simply calling `utl_file.get_line` to get the next line from the file.  It seems unlikely that is really what you're asking however.  I assume that to read a transaction, you'd call `utl_file.get_line` in a loop once you had encountered a 5 until you had an 8 but that's me guessing at the structure of your file.

Comment: yes that is what it is exactly. get into the loop, read the 5, any number of 6's, read the 8, exit the loop and go to the next iteration of the 5.

Comment: `I need logic to...` hm, sorry, please include whatever you tried before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for.  Posting code is always helpful so that we're not guessing.  I'd think that you'd want something like this where there are separate procedures defined to parse each individual type of line.

```
declare
  l_file utl_file.file_type;
  l_line varchar2(4000);
  l_in_transaction boolean := false;
begin
  l_file := utl_file.fopen( <<parameters>> );

  loop
    utl_file.get_line(l_file, l_line);
    if( substr(l_line,1,1) = '1'  and l_in_transaction = false)
    then
      parse_file_header( l_line );
    end if;
    if( substr(l_line,1,1) = '5' and l_in_transaction = false )
    then
      parse_transaction_header( l_line );
      l_in_transaction := true;
    end if;
    if( l_in_transaction = true)
    then
      parse_transaction_row( l_line );
    end if;
    if( substr(l_line,1,1) = '8' and l_in_transaction = true)
    then
      parse_transaction_trailer( l_line );
      l_in_transaction := false;
    end if;
    if( substr(l_line,1,1) = '9'  and l_in_transaction = false)
    then
      parse_file_trailer( l_line );
    end if;

  end loop;
exception
  when no_data_found
  then
    utl_file.fclose( l_file );
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. But how does the logic account for a '5' with more than one '6'?

Comment: @QuickDrawMcgraw - Well, if there is a 5, `l_in_transaction` is set to true.  Each iteration of the loop reads the next line and passes it to `parse_transaction_row` until it encounters an 8.  If every transaction detail row starts with a 6 (your requirements don't say that) then you don't need `l_in_transaction` and can just call `parse_transaction_row` whenever the first character is a 6.

Comment: im sorry i think i missed mentioning the '6' record(s) for every '5' in my original question. Ill follow your guide and see how it goes. Thank you Justin, I really appreciate it. But yes, for one or more '6's to exist, there has to be a 5.